# Classe anônima do PHP7. Quais são as vantagens?

Tags: php, php-7

De acordo com o [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.anonymous.php), a partir da versão *PHP 7* será possível definir classes anônimas.

Exemplo:

```
class SomeClass {}
interface SomeInterface {}
trait SomeTrait {}

// Instanciamos a classe anonima aqui:
var_dump(new class(10) extends SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    private $num;

    public function __construct($num)
    {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    use SomeTrait;
});
```

Quais seriam as vantagens adquiridas pela linguagem ao implementar o novo recurso da classe anônima?

Comment: Não sei se estou certo, mas acho que tem algo parecido no java.

Comment: Sim, Java e C# tem isso.

Comment: Assista meu vídeo sobre o assunto :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NgLbMo-iQU

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A principal vantagem é justamente não precisar definir a classe pra poder usá-la.

Em determinados momentos da aplicação, é preciso o uso de uma classe para, por exemplo, representar uma estrutura de dados ou herdar alguma classe que já existe e ter métodos extras. Se a classe for muito pouco usada na aplicação (por exemplo, uma vez no sistema inteiro), não vale a pena declará-la. Melhor gerar uma classe anônima em tempo de execução e usá-la.

Answer (score 2):

**Há algumas vantagens:**

Antes de entender suas vantages, é necessário entender também a importância de métodos anônimos (closures), tais como são utilizados os métodos que permitem callback (ou seja, o retorno de algo já esperado), o conceito é o mesmo para as classes.

Tais como funções anônimas (closures), classes anônimas são úteis quando apenas criadas e/ou utilizadas em tempo de execução:

```
<?php
var_dump((new class {
     public function execute() { return 12345; }
})->execute()); // 12345
```

Outra vantagem é quando utilizamos diversas classes de um mesmo **namespace**, agora será possível agrupá-las ao invés de repetir o namespace para cada classe, conforme o detalhe a seguir:

*Antes:*

```
<?php
// PHP 5.6
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>
```

*Depois:*

```
<?php
// PHP 7
use yii\helpers\{ArrayHelper, Html, Url};    
?>
```

As classes anônimas pode ser imitadas (até certo ponto, pelo menos) com relativa facilidade. Também nos permite fornecer implementações (implements) de **callback** para os seus métodos dinamicamente usando **closures**. Além de fazer todas as outras coisas que uma classe comum já faz.